# Behaviour after deleting list item from List<item> in python

Tags: python, list

In some progam languages for example PHP, deleting an item do not re-index automatically the array , i want to know the behaviour of a Python list after deleting an item with `del()`...

Comment: there are plenty of questions about modifying lists while iterating them that proof that lists get reindexed and cause problems if you iterate and change them at the same time ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing an item from the middle of a list will shift everything after that item one position closer to the start of the list.

```
l = ['a', 'b', 'c']
del l[1]
print(l)  # ['a', 'c']
print(l[1]) # c
```

Answer (score 0):

Index changes to reflect content.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about PHP. But in python, it changes

Example

```
   l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
   del l[2]
   l
```

output:--[1, 2, 4, 5, 6]